# EOF occurred in violation of protocol for ansible

Tags: openssl, ansible

I am installing ansible on a newly formatted machine(Windows 10). I have enabled WSL and I installed ansible using the following set of commands.

`` sudo apt-get-y install python-pip python-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev
pip install ansible --user
echo `PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH` >> ~/.bashrc
pip install "pywinrm>=0.2.2" ``

I wrote a simple win_ping module and it is returning this error with the following verbose.

> fatal: [192.168.6.1]: UNREACHABLE! => {
>      "changed": false,
>      "msg": "ssl: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.6.1', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, u'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)'),))",
>      "unreachable": true
>   }
>
> `TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************
>   task path: /mnt/c/ansible/test.yml:1
>   Using module file /home/xxxxxx/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/windows/setup.ps1
>   <192.168.6.1> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: xxxx on PORT 5986 TO 192.168.6.1
>   checking if winrm_host 192.168.6.1 is an IPv6 address
>   <192.168.6.1> WINRM CONNECT: transport=ssl endpoint=https://192.168.6.1:5986/wsman
>   <192.168.6.1> WINRM CONNECTION ERROR: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.6.1', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, u'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)'),))
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/chanondw/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/winrm.py", line 345, in _winrm_connect
>       self.shell_id = protocol.open_shell(codepage=65001)  # UTF-8
>     File "/home/chanondw/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 157, in open_shell
>       res = self.send_message(xmltodict.unparse(req))
>     File "/home/chanondw/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 234, in send_message
>       resp = self.transport.send_message(message)
>     File "/home/chanondw/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 256, in send_message
>       response = self._send_message_request(prepared_request, message)
>     File "/home/chanondw/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 261, in _send_message_request
>       response = self.session.send(prepared_request, timeout=self.read_timeout_sec)
>     File "/home/chanondw/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
>       r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/chanondw/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 506, in send
>       raise SSLError(e, request=request)
>   SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.6.1', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, u'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)'),))`

I am also using ansible for the same user credentials and using the same playbook. My old machine works fine, but my new machine refuses to cooperate. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe there is no certificate on the host?
Try running the host preparation script with the -ForceNewSSLCert option.
ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1 -ForceNewSSLCert